# 'NoneType' object is not callable Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, time, sleep

I am creating a program to scrape data from my school's website using python, but i've encountered a problem. I have included an input variable that lets the user decide whether to see the school calendar, emails or to exit. When i run it i receive the following error:

```
 File "school.py", line 112, in <module>
    time.sleep(2)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

As you can see, the issue is with the 'time.sleep()', which i have incorporated while using the selenium module to navigate through the website. This section of the program looks something like this:

```
if option == "calendar":
        *USING SELENIUM DRIVER TO LOGIN TO MY SCHOOL ACCOUNT*
        login_button.click()
        time.sleep(2)
```

I'm not sure why but there is an issue with how i've implemented the time module, which is strange as i made this 'calendar' program separately and it worked fine. Could somebody explain what the problem is and how to resolve it? Thanks.

Comment: You have assigned something (`None`, specifically) to the variable `time`, somewhere previously in your code.  With the reference to the `time` module gone, you can no longer use its `sleep()` function.

Comment: yes you're right, thanks for informing me @jasonharper

Comment: @jasonharper Assignment must have been made to `time.sleep` rather than `time`; in the latter case, it would have given an `AttributeError`.

Comment: No the issue was that i already had a variable named 'time', once i changed it the issue was resolved @MustafaAydın